# Javascript functional inheritance with prototypes

Tags: javascript, inheritance, performance, prototypal-inheritance

In Douglas Crockford's *JavaScript: The Good Parts* he recommends that we use functional inheritance.  Here's an example:

```
var mammal = function(spec, my) {
    var that = {};
    my = my || {};

    // Protected
    my.clearThroat = function() { 
        return "Ahem";
    };

    that.getName = function() {
        return spec.name;
    };

    that.says = function() {
        return my.clearThroat() + ' ' + spec.saying || '';
    };

    return that;
};

var cat = function(spec, my) {
    var that = {};
    my = my || {};

    spec.saying = spec.saying || 'meow';
    that = mammal(spec, my);

    that.purr = function() { 
        return my.clearThroat() + " purr"; 
    };

    that.getName = function() { 
        return that.says() + ' ' + spec.name + ' ' + that.says();
    };

    return that;
};

var kitty = cat({name: "Fluffy"});
```

The main issue I have with this is that every time I make a `mammal` or `cat` the JavaScript interpreter has to re-compile all the functions in it.  That is, you don't get to share the code between instances.

My question is: how do I make this code more efficient?  For example, if I was making thousands of `cat` objects, what is the best way to modify this pattern to take advantage of the `prototype` object?

Comment: "*has to re-compile all the functions in it. That is, you don't get to share the code between instances*" - No. The code is shared, only different function objects with different scope values need to be created. It's not a that huge overhead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you just can't do it that way if you plan on making lots of `mammal` or `cat`. Instead do it the old fashioned way (prototype) and inherit by property. You can still do the constructors the way you have above but instead of `that` and `my` you use the implicit `this` and some variable representing the base class (in this example, `this.mammal`).

```
cat.prototype.purr = function() { return this.mammal.clearThroat() + "purr"; }
```

I'd use another name than `my` for base access and store it in `this` in the `cat` constructor. In this example I used `mammal` but this might not be the best if you want to have *static* access to the global `mammal` object. Another option is to name the variable `base`.

Comment: The problem with linking the `my` object via the `this.mammal` is that I would then lose the privacy of it, as someone could just do `cat.mammal.clearThroat()` and access the protected method.

Comment: So true. If you want privacy then you need to do it by convention, for example, preceding your protected methods with underscores. If that seems too loose, consider that even this "functional inheritance" pattern is itself a convention. Javascript is not a "neat freak" language, it's much more "rough and ready." Making it work the neat freaky way costs a penalty in performance, as you found out. However, don't make too much of the penalty--it takes tens of thousands of object creations to significantly impact your overall run speed, given your example.

Comment: “someone could just do `cat.mammal.clearThroat()` and access the protected method” — not every problem needs to be solved with code. With the greatest possible respect, you are not writing Windows. If someone misuses your code, that’s awesome, because it means someone’s actually using your code. Much better to focus on making code that’s useful, and easy to use correctly, rather than guarding against hypothetical problems.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: I understand what you're saying, but I'm asking this question more to gain a deeper understanding of JavaScript than anything else.

Comment: @cdmckay I come from a functional language background and Javascript is a functional language based on Scheme. In procedural languages with type systems, you need OO semantics in order to express your way around the limitations of the type system. In Javascript, inheritance of this sort is unneeded to create polymorphism--there is no type system and so no need to express to the codebase that A is a type of B. Instead any two objects that share a set of properties can be treated as polymorphous. To share code, you can directly mix in code via prototypes and function references.

Comment: @cdmckay: ah yes, I did go off on a bit of a rant there.

Answer (score 1):

Let me introduce you to Classical Inheritance that never uses `prototype`. This is a bad coding exercise but will teach you the real **Classical Inheritance** which always compared to **prototypal inheritance**:

Make a custructor:

```
function Person(name, age){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.sayHello = function(){return "Hello! this is " + this.name;}
}
```

Make another cunstructor that inherits from it:

```
function Student(name, age, grade){
  Person.apply(this, [name, age]);
  this.grade = grade
}
```

Very simple! `Student` calls(applies) `Person` on itself with `name` and `age` arguments takes care of `grade` arguments by itself.

Now lets make an instance of `Student`.

```
var pete = new Student('Pete', 7, 1);
```

Out `pete` object will now contain `name`, `age`, `grade` and `sayHello` properties. It **owns** all those properties. They are not uplinked to `Person` through prototype. If we change `Person` to this:

```
function Person(name, age){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.sayHello = function(){
    return "Hello! this is " + this.name + ". I am " this.age + " years old";
  }
}
```

`pete` will no recieve the update. If we call `pete.sayHello`, ti will return `Hello! this is pete`. It will not get the new update.

Answer (score 0):

if you want privacy and you dont like protyping you may or may-not like this approach:

(note.: it uses jQuery.extend)

```
var namespace = namespace || {};

// virtual base class
namespace.base = function (sub, undefined) {

    var base = { instance: this };

    base.hierarchy = [];

    base.fn = {

        // check to see if base is of a certain class (must be delegated)
        is: function (constr) {

            return (this.hierarchy[this.hierarchy.length - 1] === constr);
        },

        // check to see if base extends a certain class (must be delegated)
        inherits: function (constr) {

            for (var i = 0; i < this.hierarchy.length; i++) {

                if (this.hierarchy[i] == constr) return true;
            }
            return false;
        },

        // extend a base (must be delegated)
        extend: function (sub) {

            this.hierarchy.push(sub.instance.constructor);

            return $.extend(true, this, sub);
        },

        // delegate a function to a certain context
        delegate: function (context, fn) {

            return function () { return fn.apply(context, arguments); }
        },

        // delegate a collection of functions to a certain context
        delegates: function (context, obj) {

            var delegates = {};

            for (var fn in obj) {

                delegates[fn] = base.fn.delegate(context, obj[fn]);
            }

            return delegates;
        }
    };

    base.public = {
        is: base.fn.is,
        inherits: base.fn.inherits
    };

    // extend a sub-base
    base.extend = base.fn.delegate(base, base.fn.extend);

    return base.extend(sub);
};

namespace.MyClass = function (params) {

    var base = { instance: this };

    base.vars = {
        myVar: "sometext"
    }

    base.fn = {
        init: function () {

            base.vars.myVar = params.myVar;
        },

        alertMyVar: function() {

            alert(base.vars.myVar);
        }

    };

    base.public = {
        alertMyVar: base.fn.alertMyVar
    };

    base = namespace.base(base);

    base.fn.init();

    return base.fn.delegates(base,base.public);
};

newMyClass = new namespace.MyClass({myVar: 'some text to alert'});
newMyClass.alertMyVar();
```

the only downside is that because of the privacy scope you can only extend the virtual classes and not the instanceable classes.

here is an example of how i extend the namespace.base, to bind/unbind/fire custom events.

```
// virtual base class for controls
namespace.controls.base = function (sub) {

    var base = { instance: this };

    base.keys = {
        unknown: 0,
        backspace: 8,
        tab: 9,
        enter: 13,
        esc: 27,
        arrowUp: 38,
        arrowDown: 40,
        f5: 116
    }

    base.fn = {

        // bind/unbind custom events. (has to be called via delegate)
        listeners: {

            // bind custom event
            bind: function (type, fn) {

                if (fn != undefined) {

                    if (this.listeners[type] == undefined) {
                        throw (this.type + ': event type \'' + type + '\' is not supported');
                    }

                    this.listeners[type].push(fn);
                }

                return this;
            },

            // unbind custom event
            unbind: function (type) {

                if (this.listeners[type] == undefined) {
                    throw (this.type + ': event type \'' + type + '\' is not supported');
                }

                this.listeners[type] = [];

                return this;
            },

            // fire a custom event
            fire: function (type, e) {

                if (this.listeners[type] == undefined) {
                    throw (this.type + ': event type \'' + type + '\' does not exist');
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < this.listeners[type].length; i++) {

                    this.listeners[type][i](e);
                }

                if(e != undefined) e.stopPropagation();
            }
        }
    };

    base.public = {
        bind: base.fn.listeners.bind,
        unbind: base.fn.listeners.unbind
    };

    base = new namespace.base(base);

    base.fire = base.fn.delegate(base, base.fn.listeners.fire);

    return base.extend(sub);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To proper use Javascript-prototype based inheritance you could use `fastClass` https://github.com/dotnetwise/Javascript-FastClass

You have the simpler `inheritWith` flavor:

```
  var Mammal = function (spec) {
    this.spec = spec;
}.define({
    clearThroat: function () { return "Ahem" },
    getName: function () {
        return this.spec.name;
    },
    says: function () {
        return this.clearThroat() + ' ' + spec.saying || '';
    }
});

var Cat = Mammal.inheritWith(function (base, baseCtor) {
    return {
        constructor: function(spec) { 
            spec = spec || {};
            baseCtor.call(this, spec); 
        },
        purr: function() {
            return this.clearThroat() + " purr";
        },
        getName: function() {
            return this.says() + ' ' + this.spec.name + this.says();
        }
    }
});

var kitty = new Cat({ name: "Fluffy" });
kitty.purr(); // Ahem purr
kitty.getName(); // Ahem Fluffy Ahem
```

And if you are very concerned about performance then you have the `fastClass` flavor:

```
var Mammal = function (spec) {
    this.spec = spec;
}.define({
    clearThroat: function () { return "Ahem" },
    getName: function () {
        return this.spec.name;
    },
    says: function () {
        return this.clearThroat() + ' ' + spec.saying || '';
    }
});

var Cat = Mammal.fastClass(function (base, baseCtor) {
    return function() {
        this.constructor = function(spec) { 
            spec = spec || {};
            baseCtor.call(this, spec); 
        };
        this.purr = function() {
            return this.clearThroat() + " purr";
        },
        this.getName = function() {
            return this.says() + ' ' + this.spec.name + this.says();
        }
    }
});

var kitty = new Cat({ name: "Fluffy" });
kitty.purr(); // Ahem purr
kitty.getName(); // Ahem Fluffy Ahem
```

Btw, your initial code doesn't make any sense but I have respected it literally.

`fastClass` utility:

```
Function.prototype.fastClass = function (creator) {
    var baseClass = this, ctor = (creator || function () { this.constructor = function () { baseClass.apply(this, arguments); } })(this.prototype, this)

    var derrivedProrotype = new ctor();

    if (!derrivedProrotype.hasOwnProperty("constructor"))
        derrivedProrotype.constructor = function () { baseClass.apply(this, arguments); }

    derrivedProrotype.constructor.prototype = derrivedProrotype;
    return derrivedProrotype.constructor;
};
```

`inheritWith` utility:

```
Function.prototype.inheritWith = function (creator, makeConstructorNotEnumerable) {
    var baseCtor = this;
    var creatorResult = creator.call(this, this.prototype, this) || {};
    var Derrived = creatorResult.constructor ||
    function defaultCtor() {
        baseCtor.apply(this, arguments);
    }; 
    var derrivedPrototype;
    function __() { };
    __.prototype = this.prototype;
    Derrived.prototype = derrivedPrototype = new __;

    for (var p in creatorResult)
        derrivedPrototype[p] = creatorResult[p];

    if (makeConstructorNotEnumerable && canDefineNonEnumerableProperty) //this is not default as it carries over some performance overhead
        Object.defineProperty(derrivedPrototype, 'constructor', {
            enumerable: false,
            value: Derrived
        });

    return Derrived;
};
```

`define` utility:

```
Function.prototype.define = function (prototype) {
    var extendeePrototype = this.prototype;
    if (prototype)
        for (var p in prototype)
            extendeePrototype[p] = prototype[p];
    return this;
}
```

[* Disclaimer, I am the author of the open source package and the names of the methods themselves might be renamed in future` *]